# JAVA ArrayIndexoutofBoundException issue

Tags: java, arrays

A perfect number is one that is the sum of its factors, excluding itself. The 1st perfect number is 6 because 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. The 2nd perfect number is 28 which equals 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14. The third is 496 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 31 + 62 + 124 + 248. In each case, the number is the sum of all its factors excluding itself.

Write a method named henry that takes two integer arguments, i and j and returns the sum of the ith and jth perfect numbers. So for example, henry (1, 3) should return 502 because 6 is the 1st perfect number and 496 is the 3rd perfect number and 6 + 496 = 502.

I have done this far:: but this is showing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException at this line **temp[index] = j;** please help me to solve this OutOfBound issue, Thanks..

```
public static int henry  (int a, int b){

    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int henryNumber = 0;

        for(int i=4;;i++){
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int sum = 0;

            for(int j = 1; j<i; j++){
                if(i%j == 0 ) { temp.add(j); }
            }

            for (Integer item : temp) { sum+=item; }

            if(sum == i) arr.add(i);

            if(arr.size() == b) {
                henryNumber = arr.get(a-1) + arr.get(b-1);
                break;
            }
        }

    return henryNumber;
}
```

Comment: please post the exact exception. It should tell you the value of `j`. Also, please the parameters to the call, which produced the exception.

Comment: Of course the index is out of bounds. The array length is 0! No index could possibly be in bounds! Why didn't you use the list?

Comment: Your array is always empty, as far as I can tell - so there's no array access expression that *wouldn't* throw an exception...

Comment: i am new to java dont know how exactly to use the list that way i used array,

Comment: Do not edit your question updating the code. Instead, keep it as it is and post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] temp = {};
```

This sets temp to an array of 0 elements. So when you try to access temp[index] where index is  = to 0 its out of bounds because the array doesn't have even a single element

You would need to create an array of x number elements by doing:

```
int[] temp = new int[x];
```

and then you can set the value at each of the indicies to whatever value you want.

Answer (score 1):

An array has a fixed length as soon as it it created, and that length cannot be changed.

```
int[] temp = {};
```

This creates an empty array. Its length is zero. You can't change that, you can't add any items to it.

```
temp[index] = j;
```

This tries to put something in the `temp` array. However, as I said, the array is empty, its length is zero, so any value of `index` would be out of bounds.

Using a `List` (which is commented out in your source) will allow you to create a growing collection of elements. Alternatively, you have to think of a proper size for your array, that will hold all the elements you'll be using, and use that size when you create the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
    int[] temp=new int[i];
```

instead of

```
    int[] temp={};
```

I have never assigned an array like this before.